# Accessing the scope inside the $timeout in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive  in AngularJS, with $timeout in link function.

```js
.directive('setValueInColorSelectionBlock', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{
            setValueInColorSelectionBlock:"=setValueInColorSelectionBlock"
        },
        link:function(scope, element, attrs) {
           //able to access the scope
             $timeout(function() {
               //not able to access the scope 
            });
        }
    };
});
```

My html :

```html
<div class="container-fluid" set-value-in-color-selection-block="$tbCtrl.containers">
```

*this* in $time out access the window object. I am not able to access scope inside the $timeout.

How do we access the scope?

Comment: You have the `scope` argument in the link function. It is accessible inside the timeout function.

Comment: No, I am not able to access the scope. It gives Uncaught ReferenceError: scope is not defined error.

Comment: Is `scope` accessible inside `link`?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access the scope inside the link function. But not in $timeout.

Comment: @NirajHirachan Create closure for `$timeout`. Please check if it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the current scope configuration of your directive, you are telling angular to bind your scope to a variable in the parent scope. The name of the variable is set to be decided by the value of the element attribute `setValueInColorSelectionBlock`.

And your scope will have a single property - that is `setValueInColorSelectionBlock`.

Make sure all the variable and attribute requirements to satisfy these conditions are met.

If everything is set, the scope is available inside the timeout function through link functions `scope` argument.

```
link:function(scope, element, attrs) {

             $timeout(function() {
               console.log(scope);
            });

        }
```

---

**Edit**

When the `scope` is referenced inside the timeout function, a closure is created. This closure makes sure that the local variables are still accessible even after the caller function is left.

Now, based on the comment, your problem seems to be that, even though the `scope` object is ensured by the closure, the properties of it may be deleted by the time the timeout function is executed.

You can probably take the copy of the `scope` object and save it to the local function scope for later access.

```
link:function(scope, element, attrs) {

             var savedScope = angular.copy(scope);

             $timeout(function() {
               console.log(savedScope);
            });

        }
```

Comment: Hi Charlie H. I have added the HTML. I can access the scope.setValueInColorSelectionBlock in the link function but The issue is when the $timeout is called the scope is cleared( i.e It gives scope is not defined). The context inside the $timeout is that of the window object.

Comment: Provided an edit. Please see if that solves your problem. If not, create a small fiddle to demonstrate the condition.

Comment: Hi Charlie. I have a weird issue. If I put savedScope as some string then, I am able to access the scope in the $timerOut closure but not the scope. As fir angular.copy(). Making copies of  Scope instances is not supported.

Comment: Please create a fiddle to create an instance of the error.

Comment: In this sample, you cannot access `scope.setValueInColorSelectionBlock` anywhere - not inside the timeout nor outside the timeout  - because you don't have a parent scope above the directive. Please fix your plunker to demonstrate the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to **@Charlie H**'s answer for closure. You can try this, Wrap your `$timeout` with a function with parameter and user that parameter into `$timeout` function.

```
function(eleScope){ // wrapper function with eleScope as parameter
           $timeout(function() {
               console.log(eleScope); // access eleScope paramter
        })(scope); // pass scope to closure function
    }
}
```